# QTcpSocket - An invalid handle was specified when exting QRunnable

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp

This error occurred in this snippet:

```
void TCPConnectThread::run()
{
    m_socket = new QTcpSocket();
    m_socket->setSocketDescriptor(m_fd);

    m_socket->waitForReadyRead(10000);

    QString data = m_socket->readAll();

    m_socket->waitForDisconnected();
}
```

A little deep in:

```
if (::WSAIoctl(socketDescriptor, FIONREAD, &dummy, sizeof(dummy), &nbytes,  
sizeof(nbytes), &sizeWritten, 0,0) == SOCKET_ERROR) <-Exception here
{
    WS_ERROR_DEBUG(WSAGetLastError());
    return -1;
}
```

Deeper in:

```
if (::getsockopt(d->socketDescriptor, SOL_SOCKET, 
SO_ERROR, (char *) &value, &valueSize) == 0) <-Here
```

`invalid handle` exception occurred when exiting the `run` method.

Here's how I get m_socket:

```
m_socket = new QTcpSocket();
m_socket->setSocketDescriptor(m_fd);//m_fd is the socket descriptor of another socket
                                    //from another thread
```

Here's the the thread from which `m_fd` is collected:

```
void TCPListenerThread::onNewConnection()
{
    QTcpSocket *clientSocket = m_tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
    int sockfd = clientSocket->socketDescriptor();
    m_connectThread = new TCPConnectThread(sockfd);
    m_threadPool->start(m_connectThread);
}
```

Exception:

```
Most possible exception at 0x76edf9ea in manager_host.exe:   
0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified
```

How and where may I find this invalid handle ?

Comment: how do you obtain socket descriptor?

Comment: @undercover m_fd is the socket descriptor of another socket from another thread.

Comment: Is it ensured to be a valid handle (not for instance closed)?

Comment: @undercover I don't know how to check handle validity. The exception only happens at disconnection, I think it stays valid just before disconnection ?

Comment: Sure enough. Before you disconnect both sockets work on valid handle. Interesting thing happen when you disconnect. It seems like descriptors are not refcounted which results in destroying descriptor even when other socket may refer to it. Which socket dies first, the one you obtain descriptor from or the one you set descriptor to?

Comment: @Adrian The one I set descriptor to. But the thread I obtain descriptor from does not use the file descriptor at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the socket descriptor of a `QTcpSocket` object if it is already used by another `QTcpSocket` object. There is also no method of de-assigning it once is assigned to a `QTcpSocket`

Even if you don't explicitly use the initial `QTcpSocket`, if there is an event loop in the thread it was created (which is probably the case here), Qt will monitor it in that thread.

As an alternative, you could:

- derive the `QTcpServer` class to redefine its [`incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtcpserver.html#incomingConnection) method to get that descriptor before it is assigned to a `QTcpSocket` instead of using `nextPendingConnection` **OR**
- pass directly the `QTcpSocket` you receive from `nextPendingConnection` instead of the socket descriptor as a parameter to the thread constructor, and move it to the other thread (see [that note](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtcpserver.html#notes)):

  ```
  TCPConnectThread(QTcpSocket *socket)
      : m_socket(socket) 
  {
      m_socket−>setParent(0); // necessary to move the object to another thread
      m_socket->moveToThread(this);
      ...
  }
  ```

  As the moving has to be done from the initial thread, the first alternative might be easier to do with a `QRunnable`, because you might not have access easily to the future `QThread` the runnable will be using.

Comment: Enlightened me !!! Thanks ! But I have a big problem: the `TCPConnectThread` is a `QRunnable` not a `QThread`(to use the thread pool), so I just can't move m_socket to `TCPConnectThread`... Do you have any ideas ? (deriving `QTcpServer` is a little difficult for me)

Comment: @CDT In that case, you can still write a class derived from `QTcpServer` (the first alternative).

Comment: It works great ! Saved me for a day's googling and frustration ! Thank you !